# Resizing Widget and it's child views

Tags: java, android

I have created widget which consist of many other child views (`TextView`, `ImageView`, `ProgressBar`). The problem I am getting is when I resize the widget, I want other views to also proportionately change its size and position. Now when I resize the widget layout, only background image which is set to match parent change it's size while other views remains on fixed position. Is there any way to make all the views inside the main layout to change its size too while resizing the widget.

Just look at UCCW app on Play Store. When you create a widget there and resize, all the child views changes their position and size according to it. I don't want that all the other views should just float on background.

Comment: Have you handled the `onAppWidgetOptionsChanged()` method ?

Comment: I know about this method but I think it deals with Grid Size. So if I want to change the size of views, I'll have to input it with rows and columns and there are literally 50 views inside my widget. I don't think I can deal them all with grid size. If there is a method to change all the views appropriately with new size then please guide me into it. Thanks!